# Why aren't included module methods overriding previously included module methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to conditionally override methods defined inside of a gem. My idea was to conditionally include a module with the methods I wish to override. But I'm finding that simply including a module after the module I wish to override, isn't overriding the methods as I expected. Please see example below:

These are the methods that I want to override the gem methods with:

```
module SocializationsOverideConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def follow!(followable)
    Socialization::RedisStores::Follow.follow!(self, followable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Follow.follow!(self, followable)
  end

  def unfollow!(followable)
    Socialization::RedisStores::Follow.unfollow!(self, followable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Follow.unfollow!(self, followable)

    NotificationDismissalService.new.call(followable, user: self, dont_match_trigger: true, destroy: true)
  end

  def like!(likeable)
    Socialization::RedisStores::Like.like!(self, likeable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Like.like!(self, likeable)
  end

  def unlike!(likeable)
    Socialization::RedisStores::Like.unlike!(self, likeable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Like.unlike!(self, likeable)
  end
end
```

Here is my class definition:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_liker
  acts_as_likeable
  acts_as_follower
  acts_as_followable
  acts_as_mentionable

  include SocializationsOverideConcern if $rollout.active?(:redis_to_mysql)
```

Methods follow!, unfollow! etc. are defined inside the socialization gem. and are include via the acts_as calls above.

Anyway, this is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish, to override the follow!, unfollow!, like!, and unlike! methods if the `redis_to_mysql` rollout is active.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are you sure `$rollout.active?(:redis_to_mysql)` is truthy? 2) When it is truthy, and you call `User.ancestors`, what does it output?

Comment: `include SocializationsOverideConcern if $rollout.active?(:redis_to_mysql)` is actually invalid syntax. I added it simply to show intent.

Comment: When I check User.ancestors, the Modules I want to override show up AFTER the module I want to override them with. Not sure why that is...

Comment: `include Module if condition` is not invalid. Is that what you're saying? or are you talking about the `$rollout.active?(:redis_to_mysql)` bit?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this `the Modules I want to override show up AFTER the module I want to override them with`? Meaning they have a higher index in the Array?

Comment: Yes they have a higher index in the array

Comment: `include Module if condition` is not valid ruby code.

Comment: yes, it is https://gist.github.com/msimonborg/d341762655a7d509f087091bc1d96901

Comment: Cool! Well, it's not working as expected :)

Comment: If the modules you're trying to override have higher indices then that's the behavior you should expect. Calling a method checks the modules in the order the appear in the ancestry array

Comment: How do I make the module I want to override with show up at the end of the ancestry array?

Comment: Ideally you'd want it in the `[1]` index. This would suggest it's working properly `User.ancestors # => [User, OverridingMod, OverriddenMod]`

Comment: Right, how do I make that happen?

Comment: Including the module before or after the acts_as calls yeidls the same results

Comment: You need to make sure `include OverridingMod` is being called after `include OverriddenMod` and it *should* do the trick. So I suspect the code might not be called in the order you think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150023/discussion-between-matthewalexander-and-m-simon-borg).

Answer (score 0):

If the condition becomes true at some point after the app is initialized, `send` `User` the `include` method after the condition becomes true. e.g.

```
def activate_rollout
  $rollout.activate(:redis_to_msql)
  User.send(:include, SocializationsOverideConcern)
end

$rollout.active?(:redis_to_mysql) # => false

User.include? SocializationsOverideConcern # => false

activate_rollout

$rollout.active?(:redis_to_mysql) # => true

User.include? SocializationsOverideConcern # => true
```

An alternative would be to add the conditional in the method body and use `super`

```
module SocializationsOverideConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def rollout_active?
    $rollout.active?(:redis_to_mysql)
  end

  def follow!(followable)
    return super unless rollout_active?
    Socialization::RedisStores::Follow.follow!(self, followable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Follow.follow!(self, followable)
  end

  def unfollow!(followable)
    return super unless rollout_active?
    Socialization::RedisStores::Follow.unfollow!(self, followable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Follow.unfollow!(self, followable)

    NotificationDismissalService.new.call(followable, user: self, dont_match_trigger: true, destroy: true)
  end

  def like!(likeable)
    return super unless rollout_active?
    Socialization::RedisStores::Like.like!(self, likeable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Like.like!(self, likeable)
  end

  def unlike!(likeable)
    return super unless rollout_active?
    Socialization::RedisStores::Like.unlike!(self, likeable)
    Socialization::ActiveRecordStores::Like.unlike!(self, likeable)
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_liker
  acts_as_likeable
  acts_as_follower
  acts_as_followable
  acts_as_mentionable

  include SocializationsOverideConcern
end
```

This way the module is always included but the conditional moves into the method execution. This might be preferable if you need to be able to restore the default functionality when the condition returns to `false`